# How to exclude particular component annoted with @component loading in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application having one of the component connecting to db. I want to avoid it's loading during tests run.

I am using below template for testing. Is it also possible to exclude the loading of particular component from main springboot class(MyApp.class)?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MyApp.class) 
public class MyTest { 
   // ...Hitting some rest endpoint to extract data 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using JUnit:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnMissingClass({"org.junit.Test"})
public class SomeComponent {
}
```

Or, if you activate a Spring profile for tests named `test`:

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class SomeComponent {
}
```

Note, that the later is a Spring rather than spring-boot solution

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My bad I was not specific to the question, actually I am using below template for testing. Is it also possible to exclude the loading of particular component from main springboot class(MyApp.class).


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MyApp.class)
public class MyTest {

    // ...Hitting some rest endpoint to extract data

}